# How to include a continuous Speech To Text service(using MS Cognitive Service) into an ASP.NET web application that writes to text boxes in pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to include a continuous Speech to Text service in an ASP.net application. The user uses a microphone on the client side and the speech is captured in a text box. The server side will use Microsoft's Cognitive service on Azure. I found this article https://codez.deedx.cz/posts/continuous-speech-to-text/ . I am not sure how the client side will talk to this API. Any help or sample code which captures both client and server side will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you read that article well he says : "we have used WebSockets (`SignalR`) to stream byte arrays from a client application"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to integrate Speech to text(stt) service with your asp.net application , maybe using stt service as an HTML page and integrate it as a view will be the simplest way.

I write a continuous speech to text HTML demo for you,just try the code below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body style="font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
  <!-- <uidiv> -->

  <div id="content" style="display:none">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><h1 style="font-weight:500;">Continuous speech to text demo </h1></td>
      </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><button id="startRecognizeAsyncButton">Start recognition</button>
        <button id="stopRecognizeAsyncButton">Stop recognition</button>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">Results</td>
        <td><textarea id="phraseDiv" style="display: inline-block;width:500px;height:200px"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    // status fields and start button in UI
    var subscriptionKey = "<your subscription key>";
    var serviceRegion= "<your region>";
    var phraseDiv;
    var startRecognizeAsyncButton;
    var stopRecognizeAsyncButton;
    var SpeechSDK;
    var recognizer;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      startRecognizeAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startRecognizeAsyncButton");
      stopRecognizeAsyncButton = document.getElementById("stopRecognizeAsyncButton");
      stopRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled=true;
      phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");
      var speechConfig;
      speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
      speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";
      var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
      recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

      startRecognizeAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        startRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled = true;
        stopRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled=false;
        phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

        recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        recognizer.recognized = function(s, e){
          phraseDiv.innerHTML += e.result.text;
        };
      });

      stopRecognizeAsyncButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
        startRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled = false ; 
        stopRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled = true ; 
        recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();

      });
      if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
        SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
        startRecognizeAsyncButton.disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';
        // in case we have a function for getting an authorization token, call it.
        if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {
            RequestAuthorizationToken();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <!-- </quickstartcode> -->
</body>
</html>
```

How to run it :

1. Save the code as a .html file.
2. Replace `subscriptionKey` and `serviceRegion` with your own service values , you can find them here :

[image]

3.From the [Speech SDK for JavaScript .zip package](https://aka.ms/csspeech/jsbrowserpackage) extract the file `microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js` and place it into the folder that contains this sample. Just as below :
[image]

Test Result :

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much Stanley ! It definitely helped. I now have to find a way to hide the subscription key. Maybe even try to implement the same from a code-behind file. Cheers!

Comment: @AkdeEdge Glad to know it helps . Have a  nice day !